# Upload Image to Facebook Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, facebook, cocoa, upload

I'm currently trying to upload an image from my Mac application to Facebook. To do this, I'd like for the user to simply input his username and password, and to click a button.

The only issue is, Facebook doesn't actually have an API for the Mac, it only has one for iOS. This shouldn't be a problem, except for the fact that to login, you *must* use a web view, something I'm not to keen on doing, since I'd like the interface to be two simple text fields.

I've also looked into PHFacebook, a class I found online, but it also seems to utilize an NSWebView.

I'm wondering if there's a security issue when you use text fields; indeed, it's slightly strange no available API offers this function !

So, to conclude, is it possible, or is there an API, that lets you upload an image and lets you provide the user's credentials through simple NSStrings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not supported unless you can embed a web browser.

If you scroll to the bottom of: [facebook authentication docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), it seems to say this.

Embedding a web browser is generally doable, but may be overkill for what you are trying to do.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's a Cocoa framework called [MKAbeFook](https://github.com/mikekinney/MKAbeFook) that lets you access Facebook APIs. I don't know if it's up to date, but you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through JSON on your mac app but I think the way Facebook protocols work you simply provide the image to upload and then the user logs into their Facebook account through a webview and has to authorize it.

Comment: Yes I think so. You could possible hack something together that dies what you want but it will likely break Facebooks TOS